# SoapHttpClientProtocol: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall

Tags: c#, socketexception

I use SoapHttpClientProtocol to send requests to web services. Sometimes I got SocketException: 'A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall'.
I see the following call stack:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A 
blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

...

System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

I just call `SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke` and nothing else. 
I get this issue in case of a machine with proxy and firewall. I suppose that it can be the cause but I can't understand how and what to do to fix it.

Comment: How often do you get the issue? Trying again immediately does it always work?  I suspect a timeout issue but not sure.

Comment: It happens a few times a day. The thing is that it happens on machines with firewall and proxy. On the other kind of machines it works fine.

Comment: Is the server on same machine as client?  Does your network have Group Policy?  When you are using Group Policy the connection has to be confirmed on a password server.  Sometimes the acknowledgement from the password server is taking too long or is timing out.  Is the time of failure random or consistent?  It could be a hardware issue so may be running some long pings to verify health may help.  If nothing else works you can put the code into a loop and try again when it fails.  I don't really like making that recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout using

`System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Timeout`

before you make the call.

If this doesn't work then you probably need to look at the firewall settings, assuming it never works through the firewall.